# Testcase design for verifying many textboxes on webpage

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I have webpage with 60 textinputs. All of this inputs has 'info' links which expand/collapse textbox (see [example](http://jdstiles.com/java/expandcollapsesections.html)) with description for required input. I have a file with all required strings. I need to check expand/collapse functionality and text inside textboxes. I'm wondering what is the best way to design testcase(s)? Do I need to describe all this 'info' links in my Page.class and create separate tc for each one? or I can implement it in one tc ?
As a workaround I can use txt file which contain following information for all required links `infoLinkHref | textboxContent`
but such implementation is outside of page-object model and looks dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that checkboxes have sequent numbers like in your example I would try to use next method (it kind of pseudo code)

```
public string myCheckboxText(string checkboxNameOrNumber) {
  WebElement checkbox = driver.FindElement(By.checkboxNameOrNumber);
  return textOfCheckboxToBeVerified;
}
```

In test you can verify it as `Assert.assertEquals(MyPage.myCheckboxText(checkbox_1), expectedText)` and put assertion in loop to check through number of checkboxes. `expectedText` can be enterd manually or to be read from file. I think it does not contradict PageObject pattern and your current implementation.